# Material ui : Table scroll to top of new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a bit lost on this.

I already try many settings with scrollTop.
Let me explain, I'm using material Ui and their pagination stuff with table [documentation here](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting)
so I'm stuck when I click on next set of row( or change page ), I start at the bottom. but I would like to start at the top of every new row.

If someone can help me and give me an explanation of why, A huge thanks!
sorry, I'm quite new to React.

here is my code :

```
function DisplayList(props) {
   var rows = [];
   const data = props.data;
   const searchData = props.searchData;
   const setHoverAddress = props.setHoverAddress;

   const classes = useStyles1();

   const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
   const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

   const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
       setPage(newPage);   
   };

   const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
       setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
       setPage(0);
   };


   data.map((result, index) => { // WARNING : slice here which limits the number of results: .slice(0, 5)
       const volulme = Math.round(result.volulme);
       const volulme2 = Math.round(result.volulme2);


       rows.push(
       <div id={index}>
           <ListItem 
           alignItems="flex-start"
           onMouseEnter={e => {
               console.log(index);
           }}
           >
               <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1}>
                   <Grid item xs={5}>

                   {/* <Stage width={150} height={150}>
                       <Layer>
                       <Shape
                           sceneFunc={(context, shape) => {
                           context.beginPath();
                           context.moveTo(20, 10);
                           context.lineTo(120, 80);
                           context.lineTo(120, 140);
                           context.lineTo(22, 140);
                           context.closePath();
                           // (!) Konva specific method, it is very important
                           context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
                           }}
                           fill="#00D2FF"
                           stroke="black"
                           strokeWidth={2}
                       />
                       </Layer>
                   </Stage> */}

                   </Grid>
                   <Grid item xs={7}>
                   <ListItemText
                   primary={
                   }
                   secondary={
                       <React.Fragment>
                       <Typography
                           component="span"
                           variant="body2"
                           display="inline"
                           color="textPrimary"
                       >
                           Solid2 : {volulme2}
                       </Typography>
                       </React.Fragment>
                   }
                   />
                   <ListItemText
                   secondary={
                       <React.Fragment>
                       <Typography
                           component="span"
                           variant="body2"
                           display="inline"
                           color="textPrimary"
                       >
                           Solid : {volulme}
                       </Typography>
                       </React.Fragment>
                   }
                   />
                   <FormControlLabel
                   control={
                       <Checkbox icon={<FavoriteBorder />} 
                       checkedIcon={<Favorite />} 
                       color="primary"
                       onClick={(e) => {
                           if (e.target.checked) {
                               addFavourite(parc_id, 1)
                           } else {
                               removeFavourite(parc_id, 1)
                           }
                       }}
                       name="checkedH" />
                   }
                       label="Enregistrer"
                   />
                   </Grid>
               </Grid>
           </ListItem>
       </div>
       )
   })


   return (
           <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="custom pagination table">
               <TableBody>
               {(rowsPerPage > 0
                   ? rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                   : rows
               ).map((row) => (
                   <TableRow key={index}>
                       <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                           {row}
                       </TableCell>
                   </TableRow>
               ))}
               </TableBody>
               <TableFooter>
                   <TableRow>
                       <TablePagination
                       rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, { label: 'All', value: -1 }]}
                       colSpan={3}
                       count={rows.length}
                       rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                       page={page}
                       SelectProps={{
                           inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'rows per page' },
                           native: true,
                       }}
                       onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                       onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                       ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
                       />
                   </TableRow>
               </TableFooter>
           </Table>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `scrollIntoView`?
I used `scrollTo` not working but `scrollIntoView` is fine.

```
  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    tableRef.current && tableRef.current.scrollIntoView();

    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
    setPage(0)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see scrollTop in your example, so it's tough to say exactly what the issue is. If you just trying to scroll the window try `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

If your trying to scroll the table element itself you can use a ref.

To the top of your component add:

```
function DisplayList(props) {
   const tableRef = React.createRef();
   var rows = [];
   const data = props.data;
   ...
```

Add the ref to your table:

```
  return (
  <Table
    ref={tableRef}
    className={classes.table}
    aria-label="custom pagination table"
  >
    <TableBody>
    ...
```

Finally your page event use the ref to change scrollTop

```
const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
  setPage(newPage);   
  tableRef.current?.scrollTop = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GitGitBoom . Yes I removed the scrollTop on my example . As you can see on the documentation of material UI I'm using table pagination and once I got data in it, every time I change "page" I stay at the bottom of it, I would like to be at the top

Comment: Adding ```window.scrollTo(0, 0);``` to your ```handleChangePage``` event should do it then.

Comment: A big thanks for the answer! However for answer leads to a failed to compile " Syntax error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression  "  on the       tableRef.current?.scrollTop = 0;  . And I already try the window.scrollTo(0,0); it changes nothing .... :( Thanks for you time! if you have any idea!

Comment: Yep you can either install optional chaining: (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining), or you can just use a conditional: ```if(tableRef.current) {tableRef.current.scrollTop = 0;}```. The reason being is the ```current``` property may not exist depending of the timing of the call.

Comment: Hi @GitGitBoom , thank's again for the answer ! I've try with the conditional so no error but it's not working either :/ , this thing is going to make me mad ...

Comment: HI GitGitBoom, so i tried something quite different, i added the ref in a div around my {row} , so by this I get last row (I used console.log to know) . And I change scrollTop to ScrollTo(0,-500) to test . It's working for half a second . So it's strange we see he try to scroll up but just after it's scroll back to the bottom . Any idea ?

Comment: And for the Ref in the tabl as mention in your answer it's lead to the full table

Answer (score 0):

Оn Angular Material i did like this

```
// html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #dataTable>
...
</table>

// ts
@ViewChild('dataTable') dataTable: ElementRef;

pageChange(event: { pageSize: number; pageIndex: number; }): void {
    const tableElement = this.dataTable['_elementRef']?.nativeElement;
    tableElement?.scrollIntoView();
    // set current page event.pageIndex or event.pageIndex + 1
    // get data
}
```